# Removing brackets and comma's in list

Tags: python-3.x, highcharts

I am using a list of float values as the data in a series in high charts. It will not show up because there are brackets and commas in the output.

Showing up like this:

```
[(0.078,), (33.93,), (33.374,)]
```

I need it to show up like this:

```
[0.078, 33.93, 33.374]
```

This is the python code to set the data in the series:

```
dbexecution = c.execute("SELECT column_name from table_name")
series = [{"name": 'cityname', "data": list(dbexecution)}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> L = [(0.078,), (33.93,), (33.374,)]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(0.078,), (33.93,), (33.374,)]))
[0.078, 33.93, 33.374]
```